# How do I deploy a Spring app to a production server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring MVC app built in Eclipse that I am trying to deploy as a war (to glassfish). I have an Application class that looks like this:

```
package com.jp5.rest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public static void init() {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

}
```

**Edit:**
I am getting close. The war file now deploys. But, I can not get to any of the web services end points (they all return 404s)
Now, I have a web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

And an application-context.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

    <bean id="application" class="com.jp5.rest.Application"
        init-method="init" >
        </bean>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jp5.rest"/>       
</beans>
```

The controller looks something like this:

```
package com.jp5.rest;
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/jp5/rest/message")
public class MessageRestService
{
   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/test")
   public @ResponseBody testResult test()
   {
       return new testResult(true, "test");
   }
}
```

**Edit 2**
Thanks for the pointers. The solution from here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/ was to add a class like this. I have not tested yet, but, I think this can take the place of the web.xml:

```
package com.jp5.rest;


import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class Jp5RestXML extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected void configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: a war file should run within a J2EE Web Application Server e.g. Tomcat

Comment: You have spring boot available so why deploy to glass fish? Simply create a jar and do java -jar <your-file>.jar and see everything startup... (At least if you have the spring-boot-starter-web as a dependency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the packaging, I assume this is a web application, in which a `main(...)` method wouldn't make sense.  Instead, `Application` should be initialized in your Spring configuration.

If you need to reference it anywhere else, define it as a bean in your Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="application" class="somepackage.Application" init-method="init"/>
```

Otherwise, if you just need to perform some one-time initialization stuff on startup, you can annotate the class with `@Service` or `@Component` and include the `component-scan` directive in your Spring configuration as follows:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="somepackage"/>
```

Spring is just an Inversion of Control (IoC) container that runs within the context of the web application and doesn't require any special deployment practices.  So long as the applicable Spring libraries are available to the web application (on the path of the Tomcat common classloader, or bundled with the web application), it can be deployed like any other J2EE web application.

[Spring Stereotype Annotation Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations)

Edit: If this is for a REST API, the library you are using should provide a Servlet implementation that you can add to your `web.xml`.

For example, if you are using the Restlet framework, the servlet definition would look like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>somepackage.RESTApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Substitute `somepackage.RESTApplication` with your `org.restlet.Application` implementation.

Comment: This seems to be getting me much closer. About to edit my question with where I am now

Comment: How are your servlet mappings configured?  Are you using the Spring @RequestMapping(...) annotations in your controllers?  If so, have you annotated your controllers with the @Controller annotation?

Comment: I understand your edit regarding a RESTful library. I literally started with this: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/, and adapted for my use. So, I thought Spring IS doing the REST piece.

Comment: The `SpringApplication` comes from [Spring-Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot) which does a lot of auto configuration AND allows you to start your application simply from the command line. Simply create a jar (or war if you like) do `java -jar <your-application-file>.[jar|war]` and well that is it.